# Sorting price in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado, mongoengine

I'm having trouble sorting data by price.
I want to show off the price based on the value of the price
I've tried, but the results are not as I expected.

code testing:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient().ecome
col = client['post_product']

data = []
GetData = col.find({'Category':'Handphone'}).sort([('Price', pymongo.ASCENDING)]).limit(10)
for x in GetData:
    listed = dict(
        title=x['Title'],
        price=x['Price']
    )
    data.append(listed)

print data
```

and the result:

```
[{
    'price': '10',
    'title': 'tresemse'
}, {
    'price': '200',
    'title': 'muaral winner'
}, {
    'price': '30',
    'title': 'troboca'
}, {
    'price': '400',
    'title': 'brek yule'
}, {
    'price': '50',
    'title': 'moun yus'
}]
```

the results I expect are:

```
[{
    'price': '10',
    'title': 'tresemse'
}, {
    'price': '30',
    'title': 'troboca'
}, {
    'price': '50',
    'title': 'moun yus'
}, {
    'price': '200',
    'title': 'muaral winner'
}, {
    'price': '400',
    'title': 'brek yule'
}]
```

please help !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb sort within the query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953079/mongodb-sort-within-the-query)

Comment: @felix , apparently not, this case is sorting the data based on the value of the price

Comment: this is the same probleme, your `price` field is a string, hence it is sorted as a string, ie alphabetically

Comment: if so, give your best answer. I still have not found a solution

Comment: @felix i understand now, thanks your answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how strings are sorted. You should change Price field to number if you want it to be sorted as a number and not as a string. There's no way Mongo can assume it's a number when it's not.

Comment: well, thank you very much your answer.
I will try to convert it into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

just put the following at the end of your code;

```
data.sort(key = lambda item: float(item["price"]))
```